# Logging To Logentries via Nlog in an Azure Function

Tags: azure, nlog, azure-functions, serilog, logentries

Has anyone had any luck getting their azure function to write to Logentries via nLog? Haven't been able to find any samples or docs online. Closest thing I could find was this example but doesn't take into account Logentries.

https://github.com/yorek/AzureFunctionNLog

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for your scenario?  https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/506

Comment: That might work  but I feel it's complicating what should be a simple task. I decided to switch to Serilog which doesn't use .config files so it's much easier to implement for functions

Answer (score 0):

So I decided Serilog was much easier to implement since it doesn't create or use config files like nLog does. The real goal was to get my logs to LogEntries...nLog was the tool I was trying to use to do it but Serilog turned out to be better for azure functions in my opinion

https://docs.logentries.com/docs/net-serilog

Answer (score 0):

R7Insight.NLog is now available with NetCore-support:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/r7Insight.nlog

Better late than never :)